# How to have one tabs orientation be all and the other tab be landscape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar app and I won't one tabs orientation to be all and the other tabs orientation to be landscape. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a delegate to UITabBarController, which implements this method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Then check which `UITabBarItem` was selected and adjust the orientation accordingly.